# Import local Subversion repository to bitbucket

Tags: xcode, macos, svn, bitbucket

I have a local Subversion repository on my MacOS and I want to upload an iOS project to bitbucket.

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Importing+code+from+an+existing+project#Importingcodefromanexistingproject-Importanexisting,unversionedcodeprojecttoanemptyrepository) but I can't find the *Getting Started panel*.

How can I do to upload my project to bitbucket?

Answer (score 1):

You can not upload Subversion repository to BitBucket anyway - it has **only** Git and Mercurial support

Comment: So, How can I migrate my subversion project to a git project?

Comment: @VansFannel - a) add git-svn to you Git b) clone from SVN to local Git c) add new remote for local git-repo - pre-existing BitBucket repo d) push all to BB